# How to determine if the contents of an array element (a string) contains a another variable's string inside it - awk command: match or ~/../?

Tags: linux, shell, variables, awk, comparison

I currently have a code where I want to enter a condition block if I can confirm that a substring is within another string. In this case the substring is a variable and the string is an array element. I'm cycling through the array with a for loop. Searching online I've determined that Awk does not do variable expansion within regex //. See below for my current code, note that all "..." are other non-relevant parts of my code:

```
#!/bin/bash
...
cat "${inputFile}" | awk -v mac="$mac" '
...
n=split($0,array,";");
    if(array[8]~/MAC/){
        mac=array[9];
    }
...
       #Don't both checking if first line is a duplicate of some data. We won't have storage[i] declared/values set until after the first run through "if (duplicate == 0)"
       if (inputLine!=1)
       {
            for (i=0; i<=row;++i)
            {
               if($storage[i]~/mac/)
                    {                                   
                        #Test block I want to enter
                        duplicate = 1;
                    }                    
            }
       }
     
       if (duplicate == 0)
       {
            print outputText;
            storage[row]= [concatenation of some variables with spaces];
            row++;
       }
        
...
'
```

After following some of the suggestions I'm still not entering the if block. I know that some of the storage lines (array elements) should contain a concatenation of strings that will contain the string inside the mac variable. However, I never seem to enter the if block. How am I supposed to correct the format of **~/mac/** ?

Comment: Please do add samples of input and expected output along with complete tried code, its difficult to understand it from small version of code what's going on. If you are looking for `$storage[i]~/mac/` part to be fixed: Without seeing and knowing full requirement I could say do 2 things: 1st- Create a variable `storage="$storage[i]"` you are passing shell variable to awk variable a proper way to do it in `awk` programming. 2nd- For comparison do like: `if(index(storage,max))` kind of. But again this is not tested but you could give it a shot once, cheers.

Comment: 1 - storage is created the first time under the if condition block (just above the "row++;"). I tried adding that storage="$storage[i]" but when I run the code I get a fatal error code: attempt to use scalar 'sotrage' as an array

Comment: IMHO, it will be better to share complete code snippet in your question for better understanding, also please try to add Logic of what you are trying to achieve overall(if possible briefly) so that you may get suggestion on that also in case it could be done in easier way or so, thank you.

Comment: `$storage[i]` just seems wrong.  Perhaps from bashism, your other array reference is `array[8]`. Spot the difference.

Comment: 2 - Index seems to have worked for me here! Thank you for the solution